# Why there are two 'run as maven build' options in Spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am trying my hands on Spring tool suite. I observed that it when you right click on your spring project and select `run as` then there are many options available out which two are
`7 Maven build     Alt+Shift+X,M`
`8 Maven build..`
For me it look like one and the same thing. Still I am not able to figure out the difference between it.

[image: Below is the screenshot for more details]

Comment: Why not just try them out....

Comment: I tried but as I didn't had existing Maven configuration so both options were showing the same thing.Now after adding Maven configuration I can see the difference.Absolve me if is too basic question to ask.

Comment: You are officially absolved :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one lets you pick an existing Maven launch configuration. The one with the `...` opens a new launch configuration.

Comment: I spend my time in Googling but didnt get any satisfactory answer.Thanks for the answer. :)